# How to compile typescript in Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

I'm having trouble compiling my nodejs typescript application from a Dockerfile. When I build my docker image an inspect it is missing the dist folder entirely.

Dockerfile:

```
# Template: Node.js dockerfile
# Description: Include this file in the root of the application to build a docker image.

# Enter which node build should be used. E.g.: node:argon 
FROM node:latest

# Create app directory for the docker image
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/dist

# Install app dependencies from package.json. If modules are not included in the package.json file enter a RUN command. E.g. RUN npm install <module-name>
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN     npm install
RUN     npm install tsc -g
RUN     tsc

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Enter the command which should be used when the image starts up. E.g. CMD ["node", "app.js"]
CMD [ "node", "server.js"]
```

When I run the image locally and ls to reveal files/folders:

```
# ls
node_modules  package-lock.json  package.json  src
```

Any suggestions to where i am going wrong?

Comment: I can see a few problems:
1. You mkdir /usr/src/app and WORKDIR to a non existing sub directory.
2. You run tsc before you copy your files

Answer (score 25):

As I far as I know, 
the `WORKDIR` don't have to be created by yourself.
Here's the [documentation for WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#workdir).
Afterwards you don't have to copy by hand to the specific folder,
because after `WORKDIR`command the copy command would copy the files for you.

Therefore I suggest you to use the following Dockerfile:

```
    FROM node:alpine
    WORKDIR /usr/yourapplication-name
    COPY package.json .
    RUN npm install\
        && npm install typescript -g
    COPY . .
    RUN tsc
    CMD ["node", "./dist/server.js"]
```

As a tiny tipp: I would use typescript as a dependency in my `package.json` and then just use the following file:

```
    FROM node:alpine
    WORKDIR /usr/yourapplication-name
    COPY package.json .
    RUN npm install
    COPY . .
    RUN tsc
    CMD ["node", "./dist/server.js"]
```

Comment: The latter returns: `/bin/sh: 1: tsc: not found`.

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman: For that typescript has to be a dependency for your project (as I wrote in my answer). Then the npm install would install all dependencies for your project and the command tsc will be found

Comment: I'd like to eleborate my problem further in this chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207651/docker-npm-and-typescript, I'd be greatful, if you would find the time to help me!

Comment: What is the difference between "npx tsc" and "tsc"?

Comment: @SadequsHaque `npx tsc` would not dirrectly use the `node_modules`. Though you can't rely that the version from your `package.json` is used. Though `tsc` would be the version from `./node_modules/.bin/tsc`. And I would link this post https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/npm-vs-npx-whats-the-difference/

Comment: how would you watch the changes in src for development phase if you do this?

Comment: @Max adding typescript as a dependency does not magically add tsc to the PATH unless installed globally with `-g`. It's just wrong.

Comment: following this answer, I got the error `:/bin/sh: 1: tsc: not found` I thing we should install tsc not typescript in the docker file.

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me hope this will work for you too.

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /usr/test
COPY . .
RUN yarn  && yarn add typescript tsc ts-node && yarn build
CMD ["node", "./dist/index.js"]
```