# Issue with running node ts project with docker

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker

I just started learning Docker and i'm trying to run my node ts app with few simple commands. Already googled and tried a lot of things but still no success. App works perfectly when i run it directly from terminal, so mistake might only be in the Dockerfile, nothing else crossed my mind.
It always builds successfully, but breaks when i try to run.
[image: Dockerfile]
[image: Output]

```
FROM node:14.17.1-alpine
# Install base packages
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
# Change TimeZone
RUN apk add --update tzdata
ENV TZ Europe/Berlin
# Clean APK cache
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
ENV NODE_ENV=production
CMD ["node","src/app.ts"]
```

Any help would be really appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: do u run `.ts` files with node locally?

Comment: @Aritra Chakraborty I can run them locally with success, and also app works on server just as well.

Comment: Don't post images of text. Copy-paste the the text into the question and format it as a code block.

Comment: @StefanStanković u cannot run .ts file with Node. Cause typescript needs to be compiled to JS before running with node.

Comment: @super Forgot it, will do.

Comment: @Aritra Chakraborty Yap, i already know about that and that's the reason i've already tried chaning tsconfig.json file and also versions of node image inside the Dockerfile... :/

Comment: How do you expect nodejs to execute typescript code?

Answer (score 0):

Typscript app cannot be run with Node. You need to compile `.ts` files to `.js` files and then you can run `.js` file with Node.

For more detailed you can checkout a blogpost on how to containerize. For example: https://itnext.io/dockerize-a-typescript-app-in-15-mins-a0e8c1e904b3

But there is ts-node, REPL kind of thing for TS. You can add it in the package.json as devDependencies and then can do:

```
CMD ["npx", "ts-node", "src/app.ts"]
```

You can check more here: [How to run TypeScript files from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535879/how-to-run-typescript-files-from-command-line)

**EDIT:**
if you have tsconfig file then you can install `tsc` and run it in the Dockerfile to compile. Then you can run the compiled **JS** file in Node.

You can take hint from this: [How to compile typescript in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083134/how-to-compile-typescript-in-dockerfile)

```
RUN npm install tsc -g
RUN tsc
CMD ["node", "<urapppath>/app.js"]
```

Comment: Now there's different error, not seeing imports ...
Cannot find module in a few places :/
Those are imports from the different repository, why would that even be a problem.

Comment: what method are u following? tsc or ts-node? also do the same thing locally run all the commands locally.. maybe remove node_modules folder to get a sense of what is the problem. but probably it's better to close this question and create another question.